# Disable Google Analytics using javascript in Selenium

Tags: selenium, google-analytics, selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium to test a production site. The test activity screws with the analytics.

Can I disable the analytics using JavaScript after the page has loaded, via Selenium? I know I can execute JS via Selenium. The question is, how to disable the GA code?

Comment: Another option would be to add a filter in GA for your IP address of the Selenium server if that's possible

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are few options you might try. Some were taken from this blog post -
 [Exclude Selenium WebDriver traffic from Google Analytics](http://yizeng.me/2017/01/08/exclude-your-selenium-webdriver-traffic-from-google-analytics/).

**Option 0: Avoid testing live production sites**

Ideally automated Selenium UI testing is preferred to test against some kind of testing environment, instead of mess around live production databases. As live production sites only need some manual exploratory/smoke testing. In this case, when setting up the testing environment, use a different Google Analytics tracker or even avoid using Google Analytics.

**Option1: Disable JavaScript**

Since Google Analytics tracking is done by executing a snippet of JavaScript code, disable JavaScript in browsers would do. But this isn't practical, because surely this will impact the functionality of the site.

**Option2: Set user agent and exclude user agent**

Set a special testing user agent when start WebDriver, then in your source, use JavaScript to exclude that user agent.

For example, your GA should be:

```
if (user agent != your special testing user agent) {
    your GA code
}
```

**Option3: Exclude IP/ISP**

Set it in your GA's admin settings

**Option4: Opt-out plugins**

Start your WebDriver a GA opt-out plugin (only possible with ChromeDriver and FirefoxDriver). [Google Analytics Opt out Add ons](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout)

**Option5: Custom variables (cookies) with JavaScript**

See "Set a Cookie with JavaScript" section in [Best Ways to Exclude Internal Traffic in Google Analytics](http://www.seerinteractive.com/blog/best-ways-to-exclude-internal-traffic-in-google-analytics)

**Option6: Use a proxy like BrowserMob Proxy**

[BrowserMob Proxy](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy) allows manipulating HTTP requests and responses, capturing HTTP content, and exporting performance data as a HAR file. It supports blacklisting which can be used as a way of blocking data sent to Google Analytics.

```rb
require 'browsermob/proxy'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

server = BrowserMob::Proxy::Server.new("./browsermob-proxy-2.1.4/bin/browsermob-proxy", :log => true)
server.start

proxy = server.create_proxy
proxy.blacklist("https?:\/\/www\.google-analytics\.com\/.*", 404)

profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile.proxy = proxy.selenium_proxy

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => profile

proxy.new_har "browsermob"
driver.get 'http://yizeng.me/'

har = proxy.har
har.entries.first.request.url
har.save_to "./browsermob.har"

proxy.close
driver.quit
```

**Option7: Remove GA code using Selenium JavaScriptexecutor**

Your idea, but not sure if this is possible, once GA code is loaded, it's been executed, using Selenium to remove to code has to be somehow after that?

Answer (score 2):

By the power of --host-resolver-rules

```
let chrome = require("selenium-webdriver/chrome");
const chromeOptions = new chrome.Options();//.headless();
chromeOptions.addArguments('--host-resolver-rules=MAP www.google-analytics.com 127.0.0.1');
var $browser = new $driver.Builder()
    .forBrowser("chrome")
    .setChromeOptions(chromeOptions)
```

I learned it from [Can I automate Chrome request blocking using Selenium-webdriver for Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46891301/can-i-automate-chrome-request-blocking-using-selenium-webdriver-for-ruby) and it is working great.

Answer (score -1):

Somewhat late, but a low tech option if you're using a view engine, e.g. `Razor`, is to have a property on the view model such as IsTestEnvironment. Set this at run-time based on a configuration or Environment value and then test for it in the `JavaScript`, e.g.

```
@if (!Model.IsTestEnvironment){
   // Google Analytics tracking code.
}
```

Then the tracking script will only be included on your chosen environments.