# Automate Chrome request blocking using Selenium-webdriver for python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, chrome-devtools-protocol

Can I automate Chrome request blocking using Selenium-webdriver for python?
Python,Selenium,ChromeDriver,Chrome Devtool protocol.

```
1# from selenium import webdriver
2# driver = webdriver.Chrome()
3# driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setBlockedURLs', {"urls": ["www.baidu.com"]})
4# driver.get("https://www.baidu.com")
```

---

It seems '3#' is inopreative. 
How can I modify above codes?

Comment: See this similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46891301/can-i-automate-chrome-request-blocking-using-selenium-webdriver-for-ruby

Answer (score 2):

```
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setBlockedURLs', {"urls": ["www.baidu.com"]})
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.enable', {})
```

Comment: Please add some explanation and not just 2 lines of code.